# Acess specific git commit from html

Tags: git, version-control

How does one access a specific commit, without using git, from withhin an html or php file?

Ideally, Id like to use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/library/git/{sha1-hash of commit here}/core.js">
```

Is that possible, or are there other, possibly better solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with standard git tools.

You will need to have a working tree of each commit to be able to do that. That would be expensive (depending on the size of you codebase of course) in terms of disk space.

An other way would be to use a script (for example in php) to parse your request, executing a git command for the correct version and return it.

Something like this:

```
<?php
$rev = $_GET['rev'];
$file = $_GET['file'];
echo system("git show $rev:$file");
?>
```